# How to animate fire without the fire freezing

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation, effects

I want to animate my fire effect and for some reason when i get it clipped into the scene it just freezes and does not flow like a fire should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently needed to adjust the start and end frame of the fire from thedomains smoke cache[image]